# Display SQL query results as one page in html notebook

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm running a SQL query in an html notebook and I can't figure out how to display the whole result set (16 rows) on one page.

I've tried setting chunk options like `max.print = 16`, `rows.print = 16`, `paged.print = FALSE`; global chunk options like `knitr::opts_knit$set(sql.max.print = 16)`; and YAML options like `df_print: default` but the output is still a paged table displaying 10 rows per page.

````
---
title: "reprex"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r setup}
db <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:") # temporary db, no file backing
DBI::dbWriteTable(db, "quux", data.frame(column = 1:20))
```

```{sql, connection=db, max.print = 20, paged.print = FALSE}
SELECT column
FROM quux
```
````

Comment: Good question. Looking at this and comparing with [rstudio/rmarkdown#1403](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1403), your code works if using `html_document` vice `html_notebook`, so perhaps either there is a misunderstanding of where this should work, or there's a missed-step in the `html_notebook` processing. Perhaps this deserves [creating an issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/new)?

Comment: BTW: for "perfect" reproducibility, I'm going to suggest an edit that creates a temporary database for ease of testing. Feel free to revert it or change it if you'd like, just thought it'd be useful and easy for others (and you) to test.

Comment: thanks @r2evans for the edit and the suggestion. i'll render as `html_document` for now and create an issue